# Want to understand a relation

Tags: swift

I am a beginner learning Swift 3 in Xcode 8 and I was building a basic app called "Eggtimer". The code is written below and I don't understand how the `timerlabel.text` is linked to timer even I didn't set any  connection between them.

Next to the star `//*` we can also write `} else { timer.invalidate()` and the `labeltimer.text` nicely stops decreasing, how it can  happen? What does the `selector` in `timer` properties mean?
Sorry for my English and thanks for your answers.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer = Timer()
    var time = 210

    func decreasetimer() {
        if time > 0 {
            time -= 1
            timerlabel.text = String(time)
        } else { //*
            timerlabel.text = String(time)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var timerlabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func timerstarter(_ sender: AnyObject) {        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.processtimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: When executing the code, a timer waits until a certain time interval has elapsed and then fires, sending a specified message to a target object. Here, the timeinterval is 1. target is your ViewController object. Message will be sent to the function in the selector. 

I believe that you already know the above. To get good understanding on how this works, I suggest you to take a look at documentation on RunLoops.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/runloop

Comment: maybe if you take a look at the e.g. `-processtimer(:_)` method's body you might see some connection between them; this current snippet does not show that method at all, you probably forgot to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start from the bottom: `selector` specifies the method which should be called every 1 second (`timeInterval` parameter). In your case this should be changed to the following:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.decreasetimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

As you can see the `selector` is called `decreasetimer`, which is the method you specified in the top.

The timer now calls this method every time it updates. In this method you decrease the `time` var and update the text of the `timerlabel`.

`timer.invalidate()` stopps the `timer` when `time` reaches 0.

I hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: Thank you Hannes. it sounds like the timer is doing the role of "While..." but with a regular interval of time.